# Remote devcontainer, inherit SSH of parent host

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I am trying to use VSCode dev containers under a remote machine which is authenticated with git, without re-authenticating from the dev container.

Is it possible for a dev container to use the SSH agent of the parent host?

```
[  Client  ] -> [  Host ->  [  Dev Container  ]  ]
  Can auth        Can auth     Needs to use
  with Host       with git     Host's auth
                  via SSH
```

The host is opaque in it's authentication mechanisms, so simply copying `id_rsa` doesn't work. The SSH agent needs to be forwarded.

Comment: It's certainly *possible* since ssh implementations support the idea of a "jump host".  Look into setting up a jump host for your particular ssh implementations. Search for that specific phrase, or as one word "jumphost".

Comment: That’s what im thinking! But all I can find leads me to sharing the keys of the local vscode client, not the vscode server host. @torek

Comment: Really? Even without using google, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jumphost+ssh returns 137 results for me.

Comment: @torek The trouble is I don't think that the last jump from Host to Dev Container is done over SSH.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean: many (all?) answers talk about forwarding the local ssh agent (in the dev container) to the host and having the host use that same key-pair. You want the host to use the *host's* key, right? So you don't want agent forwarding; instead, you want a key to be installed *on* the host. That's definitely an ssh issue. Not having done this particular trick myself, I don't know for sure how you configure ssh to do it.

Comment: @torek I want to forward the ssh agent of the remote host to the dev container that runs on the remote host. The jumps are `vscode client -> ssh -> remote host -> ??? -> dev container`. The `remote host` has an ssh agent that is authenticated with our git repository, I want to use it within the dev container.

Comment: Agent forwarding starts with an `ssh` command. If you're not on the host initially, running `ssh devcontainer` to get *into* the dev container, there's nothing to forward. (If there's already an agent running *on* the host, and you have appropriate permissions and information, you could hook up an ssh coming *from* the dev container *to* that agent, but that's getting complicated.)

Comment: @torek It should be possible by forwarding the ssh agent as a socket(?). Something like this: https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/8699521 but VS Code doesn't really expose the ability to modify the docker launch command in that way I believe.

Comment: The ssh agent *is* (accessed through) a socket on Unix-like systems (I have no idea what they use on Windows-like systems). The path name of that socket is found in env variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` . Gaining access to the correct path is going to be tricky ("getting complicated"). Since it's a Unix-domain socket, it doesn't cross OS boundaries. Normal ssh agent forwarding causes the server's sshd to set up a *new* (second) socket; this extra socket relays requests back to the client `ssh` command's agent.